# What is the best way to remove rows in Pandas DF after a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas

I'll try to explain simple. I have a dataframe like this with more columns

```
d = {'Id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'Val': ['Yes', 'Stop', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Stop', 'Yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
    Id  Val
0   1   Yes
1   1   Stop
2   1   Yes
3   1   Yes
4   2   Yes
5   3   Yes
6   3   Stop
7   3   Yes
```

Which is ordered by Id and every Id have at least one 'Stop' Value but maybe do not have a 'Yes' value.

My goal is on every Id drop all rows with value 'Yes' after the value 'Stop' on that same Id but keep the previous and the Stop so the result should be this one:

```
    Id  Val
0   1   Yes
1   1   Stop
4   2   Yes
5   3   Yes
6   3   Stop
```

As mention earlier I have more columns with information I want to keep so doing groupby is not an option.
What is the most efficient way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

PD: Sorry if any grammar mistakes english is not my first language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is compare index values per groups with first `index` of `Stop` value and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
f = lambda x: x.index <= x.eq('Stop').idxmax()
mask = df.groupby('Id')['Val'].transform(f)
df = df[mask]
print (df)
   Id   Val
0   1   Yes
1   1  Stop
4   2   Yes
5   3   Yes
6   3  Stop
```

Or is possible use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), but is necessary shifting for select also `Stop` rows:

```
mask = (df['Val'].eq('Stop').groupby(df['Id'])
                 .apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
                 .fillna(0)
                 .eq(0))

df = df[mask]
print (df) 
 Id   Val
0   1   Yes
1   1  Stop
4   2   Yes
5   3   Yes
6   3  Stop
```